# Android Application class's variables init problme: keep nullpointerexception error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, android

I'm not very professional java programmer so I got confused about its init or instantiation.

I plan to put some global variables, or data structures into application class so I could access them everywhere in the app. So what I do was like:

```
public class myApp extends Application {
    private MyHomeInfo myHomeInfo;
    private MyWorkInfo myWorkInfo;
    RequestData requestData;

    /**All getters and setters **/
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    myHomeInfo = new MyHomeInfo;
    myWorkInfo = new MyWorkInfo;

    getMyHomeInfo.setWorkPlace('someplace');
}

setMyHomeInfo(requestData.distanceFromWork(myHomeInfo.getWorkPlace);
```

Something like this. What I get during debug is that the variables are inited during onCreate, which they are not null anymore. But once after exit onCreate function, they become null again . So when I call other functions in application class I got a nullPointerException error.

Can anyone suggest a method to overcome this problem? I know I might create some temp variables to store data then init them, but that will make code a little hard to read.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

requestData is null and your doing:
      setMyHomeInfo(requestData.distanceFromWork(myHomeInfo.getWorkPlace);

thus null pointer on the requestData obj

Comment: Thanks for replay. I actually put requestData = new requestData() in to code but still not working. So I split last code and it seems, the data saved into myHomeInfo during onCreate are lost. It become null again. Which I can't figure out why...

Comment: You'd need to actually post code and the logcat of the null pointer for me to follow what your talking about if your initializing that obj as a member variable then indeed that obj can't be null or 'go back to null' w/o you messing w/ it.